# why does not work in the form of validation?

Tags: python, django

please help correct the shape.

I create a form to enter AuthenticationCustomForm (inherit it from AuthenticationForm):

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class AuthenticationCustomForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(
        label='Имя пользователя',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Логин',
        }),     
    )

    password = forms.CharField(
        label='Пароль', 
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Пароль',
        }),
    )
```

then create in views.py:

```
def login(request):
    if(request.method == "POST"):
        form = AuthenticationCustomForm(request.POST)
        with open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "1.txt"), "wb") as f:
            f.write(bytes('1', 'UTF-8'))        
        if form.is_valid():
            with open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "2.txt"), "wb") as f:
                f.write(bytes('2', 'UTF-8'))            
            username = request.POST.get('username', '')
            password = request.POST.get('password', '')

            user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None and user.is_active:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/' + str(request.user.pk) + '/')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationCustomForm()   

    t = loader.get_template('accounts/login.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
        'form': form, 
    }, [custom_proc])   
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

login.html:

```
<form class="login_form" action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="cell">
        {{ form.username }}

        {{ form.username.errors }}
    </div>  

    <div class="cell">
        {{ form.password }}

        {{ form.password.errors }}
    </div>              

    <div class="cell">
        <input class="submit btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Войти" />
    </div>
</form>
    </form>
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('drummersaransk',
    url(r'^accounts/auth/$', 'views.auth_view', name='auth_view', ),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'views.logout', name='logout', ),    
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'views.login', name='login', ),
    url(r'^accounts/loggedin/$', 'views.loggedin', ),
    url(r'^accounts/invalid_login/$', 'views.invalid_login', ),
)
```

the problem is that the form does not work. the file is '1. txt 'written and file '2. txt' is not recorded.

Comment: form.is_valid doesn't work? and what error you will see in {{form.password.error}} and {{form.username.error}}

Comment: Errors are not displayed

Comment: So please show us the content of urls.py

Comment: @MortezaIpo Why are you so sure about it?

Comment: @EugeneSoldatov because I  have tested it ;)

Comment: @MortezaIpo have you tested it with wrong password?

Comment: @EugeneSoldatov yes I have tested with correct and wrong data. maybe I have got wrong.

Comment: Sorry. Seems it my mistake, this error should be displayed through {{form.errors}}

Answer (score 1):

You can do it instead:

**urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
from hello.forms import AuthenticationCustomForm
url(r'^accounts/login/$', login , {'authentication_form':AuthenticationCustomForm,'template_name':'login.html'} ,name='login'),
```

Comment: now fails redirection after successful authentication. before heading the user after login here return HttpResponseRedirect ('/' + str (request.user.pk) + '/'), and now he goes to a page with the authorization form

Comment: yes , I have checked https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py but I didn't find any way.

Comment: here solution:
form = AuthenticationCustomForm(data=request.POST)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

```
form = AuthenticationCustomForm(data=request.POST)
```

Comment: This is works fine . but when you redirect to /accounts/profile/ instead (my way) it will show your details and doesn't need userid in url.

Answer (score 0):

There is check for user exist and active in AuthenticationForm clean() method:

```
def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if username and password:
            self.user_cache = authenticate(username=username,
                                           password=password)
            if self.user_cache is None:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['invalid_login'],
                    code='invalid_login',
                    params={'username': self.username_field.verbose_name},
                )
            elif not self.user_cache.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['inactive'],
                    code='inactive',
                )
        return self.cleaned_data
```

So it seems like you pass wrong login or password. Just output {{form.errors}} and you will see error.